# Unable to install easyphp dev server 16.1

Tags: easyphp

I am trying to install easyphp devserver 16.1 on Windows 10 64 bit.

I  installed Visual studio 2015, but I am keep getting error message:

> MSVCR110.DLL is missing from your computer

I have also installed VC11  and VC9 builds.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling few days, I am able to installed successfully by manually copy pasting msvcr110.dll into system32 and sysWOW64.